# How do I use DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.GoToDefinition") in a VS2010 C++ macro?

Tags: c++, vba, visual-studio-2010

I recorded a macro that includes a keypress of F12 (Go To Definition), but the recording omits the second parameter that is passed to DTE.ExecuteCommand, causing the macro to crash during execution. Presumably the second arg is the name of the function I want to find, but I can't figure out how to get and pass the value. If I select the function or method name (but not the args or the class prefix), I can use DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text.ToString to pass the selection, but instead of jumping to the definition, it returns the both the .h file and the .cpp file in the Find Symbol Results window.

(And I'm not sure selection is really what I want, though I could probably get the macro to select the "right thing" if that's the way to go.  Is there any way to see what F12 is passing, just to see what it looks like? Or better yet, find out what programmatic object F12 is passing?

Vs2010 Pro

Comment: A TemporaryMacro with DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.GoToDefinition") works just fine on my machine without the second parameter.

Comment: What version of VS? What language? How did you run the macro?

Comment: VS 2010 Ultimate, C#, Macros - Run TemporaryMacro. Now tried with a C++ project and got the "Command requires one argument" error.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. Wonder what the difference is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out running the same command via IVsUIShell works:

```
    Dim cmd As EnvDTE.Command
    Dim shell As Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsUIShell
    Dim arg As Object
    Dim guid As System.Guid
    Dim serviceProvider As System.IServiceProvider

    serviceProvider = New Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ServiceProvider(CType(DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider))
    shell = serviceProvider.GetService(GetType(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.SVsUIShell))
    cmd = DTE.Commands.Item("Edit.GoToDefinition", 0)
    guid = New System.Guid(cmd.Guid)
    shell.PostExecCommand(guid, cmd.ID, 0, arg)
```

The code works as is in Visual Commander. To run it from Visual Studio macros IDE, you need to add references to

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.dll
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.10.0.dll
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.dll
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.8.0.dll
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.9.0.dll
```

And to add references you first need to copy these files to the [Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/345xe6tb%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).