# Is there a way to customize the behavior of Visual Studio F12 jump to definition?

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense, visual-studio-extensions

Visual Studio can jump to the symbol definition when press F12 over a symbol. Can I modify this behavior so the symbol resolving can be customized? For example, can we reference some other ***rule files*** to resolve the symbol.

I want to do this because my project has some special linking rules which decides which symbols get linked. But Visual Studio cannot follow such rule files by default.

For example, I have 4 C projects in a solution:

- project 1: defines `functionX()`.
- project 2: **also** defines a `functionX()` **with the same name and signature**. But the implentation is different.
- project 3: invokes `functionX()` but its ***rule file*** mandates that the linked implementation comes from project 1.
- project 4: **also** invokes `functionX()` but its ***rule file*** mandates that the linked implementation comes from project 2.

Currently, when I press F12 on `functionX()` in project 3/4, Visual Studio just lets me choose between implentations from project 1/2. I want to avoid this tedious manual selection by bringing in the rule files as a reference.

Is such customization possible?

Comment: if you want to achieve it by using visual studio extension, please refer to the following thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22344868/how-can-i-perform-go-to-definition-programmatically-in-visual-studio

Comment: @ColeWu-MSFT It looks promising. I will take a look. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

There are many [extension types][1] I can do with Visual Studio. What interests me most is the [Visual Studio-based application][2].

I will put my findings at below thread as my search goes on.

[How to add C/C++ language service to a Visual Studio-based application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46874880/how-to-add-c-c-language-service-to-a-visual-studio-based-application)