# How to add C/C++ language service to a Visual Studio-based application?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I am trying to create a domain specific IDE based on Visual Studio shell. I followed the [walk-through](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/shell/walkthrough-creating-a-basic-isolated-shell-application) to create a basic Isolated Visual Studio Shell Application.

Then I started the basic shell application and drag a C file into it. There's no syntax highlighting because no language service is included yet.

I found [the GUIDs for various Visual Studio feature packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/shell/package-guids-of-visual-studio-features). I was expecting some kind of language feature package for C/C++ listed there so I can just add it into my IDE's feature list. But there's not.

So how can I make my IDE recognize the C/C++ language?

Or put it another way, how can I customize Visual Studio to include only features I need?

### Some References

There are many [extension types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/starting-to-develop-visual-studio-extensions) I can do with Visual Studio. What interests me most is the [Visual Studio-based application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/shell/shell-isolated-or-integrated). I will put the findings here as my research goes on.

[Walkthrough: Creating a Basic Isolated Shell Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/shell/walkthrough-creating-a-basic-isolated-shell-application)

[Package GUIDs of Visual Studio Features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/shell/package-guids-of-visual-studio-features)

[Legacy Language Service Extensibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/legacy-language-service-extensibility)

[New Editor and Language Service Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/editor-and-language-service-extensions)

- [New Extending the Editor and Language Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/extending-the-editor-and-language-services)]
- [Language Service and Editor Extension Points](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/language-service-and-editor-extension-points)

[Visual Studio Isolated Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/shell/visual-studio-isolated-shell)

- [Elements of the Isolated Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/shell/elements-of-the-isolated-shell)
- [Customizing the Isolated Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/extensibility/customizing-the-isolated-shell)
- [Extending the Isolated Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/shell/extending-the-isolated-shell)

[Visual Studio Integrated Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/shell/visual-studio-shell-integrated) says this:

> No programming language is included. However, the integrated shell
>   does provide ***a framework that allows you to add programming languages***.

Comment: If you want to include Visual Studio's C++ language service, that is not possible, and it's more a legal issue, beyond technical difficulties. You cannot add features from Visual Studio to your Isolated Shell app (you can only *exclude* things), as you could very easily build another Visual Studio competitor with your app. You can however include your own language, with your own parser, etc. This is not customization, it's extension. An awful amount of work. IronPython was an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087937/is-there-a-custom-language-add-in-for-visual-studio-2012-vs11