# Programmatically go to the start of a function definition after opening a file in Visual Studio with help of DTE

Tags: c#, visual-studio, envdte

Firstly I am able to open a particular file programmatically in Visual Studio editor, with the help of [How to programmatically open project/solution in already running Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43385918/how-to-programmatically-open-project-solution-in-already-running-visual-studio).

```
  var dte = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(_DTE)) as DTE2;
  dte.ExecuteCommand("File.OpenFile","Program.cs");
```

After opening the file, I need to go directly to the line where the function definition starts(function name will be provided before opening the file) programmatically.

Does anyone knows how to go about this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I perform "Go To Definition" programmatically in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22344868/how-can-i-perform-go-to-definition-programmatically-in-visual-studio)

Comment: If you can work with the [ActiveDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte80.dte2.activedocument) or [ActiveWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte80.dte2.activewindow), you could use the [Find Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.find) (from `Document.DTE`) to locate text in the current Document. Configure the Find object (`Action`, `Target`, `FindWhat`) and execute it.